# Не сохраняется изображение в БД

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сохранить изображение в БД, но при клике на загрузить - ничего не происходит.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" 
                                 onchange="document.getElementById('photo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>                     

<?php
include_once('db.php');
print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); 
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $sesion_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $idf = ($_SESSION['userid']);

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
if(empty($_FILES['file']['size']))  die('Вы не выбрали файл');
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (5 * 1024 * 1024)) die('image size <5mb');
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$arr = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
if(!in_array($imageinfo['mime'],$arr)) echo ('image format');
 else {

$upload_dir = '/public_html/'; 
$name = $upload_dir.date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$mov = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$name);
  if($mov) {

$name = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($name)));
 if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET IMAGE='$name' WHERE id='".$idf."'")) {echo $mysql->error;}else{ echo 'All Ok';};
  }
  else echo 'Error';
 }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Зачем задавать тот же вопрос с тем же кодом, не добавив проверку на "авторизацию"... 
}
} else echo "Session not found";
?>

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков  но я в этот момент залогинен

Comment: Что выводит с кодом из комментария выше? =) добавить куда его поняли? после последней скобки } добавить else echo "Session not found";

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Выдает  Session not found

Comment: <?php session_start();?> в самое начало файла, первой строкой...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at ................ in

Comment: автостарт сессии? =) тогда выводите содержимое сессии (к остальным выводам print_r($_SESSION); и смотрите что там есть. может опечатка в искомой переменной, может вы ее не установили, но проблема как вы можете видеть именно в этой части.

Comment: @Midnight Нужно поставить session_start() в самое начало, то есть впереди всего текста

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков т.е в начало все html страницы?

Comment: @WanSpi Проглядел я... ошибку прочел неверно...
**Midnight** Чем редактируете файлы? во первых да, <?php session_start();?> это самое начало, до любого символа... во вторых проверить\удалить из файла bom если он там есть

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков встроенным в хостинг редактором

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков теперь, после клика загрузить, выдает : move_uploaded_file(/public_html/2018092002573512345.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
и еще : move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php3RUYZx' to '/public_html/2018092002573512345.png' in

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов
Это касаемо BOM, теперь касаемо session_start() - он должен располагаться всегда до любого вывода.

Comment: добавил session_start() в начало страницы, ошибки я написал выше

Comment: $name = date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
тогда файл будет находится рядом с вашим скриптом. не нужно указывать путь от корня.

Comment: Кажется все! на хостинг сохраняет, в таблицу БД тоже! Спасибо огромное за помощь! А не подскажете, как мне теперь можно выводить данную картинку в необходимых местах?(допустим как аватарку)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а не подскажете, как мне хранить ссылки в БД? в поле image